# Bad credential with Spring Cloud Config server when security is enable

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-cloud-config

I create a Spring Cloud Config server. I put security in my `application.properties` file

```
security.basic.enabled=false
security.user.name=1user
security.user.password=123
```

When I try to log to the application with the name and password, I always get

> Bad credentials

I tried to put enabled to true but get same result. I saw in the command line then spring generate random password like

> 69dfeb52-6320-4085-bcd1-22ee7a3676a2

if I use with with username user, I can connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

>

Hi [Robert Trudel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1095362/robert-trudel)

If you are using Spring Boot 2.x, then you need to prefix these properties with `spring` 
 as shown below:

```
spring.security.user.name=1user
spring.security.user.password=123
```

Also, you do not need this `security.basic.enabled=false`.

Hope this helps!